# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataset into one
here is the code I have written

```
application_prev_data = application_data.merge(previous_application, left_on='SK_ID_CURR', right_on='SK_ID_CURR', how='inner')

application_prev_data.head()
```

But it keeps giving me an error message.. what should I do? any suggestions?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f97d87cba0a8> in <module>
----> 1 application_prev_data = application_data.merge(previous_application, left_on='SK_ID_CURR', right_on='SK_ID_CURR', how='inner')
      2 application_prev_data.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5128             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5129                 return self[name]
-> 5130             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5131 
   5132     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'
```

I have the latest version of pandas (or at least that's what I believe)

```
Python: 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Numpy: 1.18.1
Pandas: 1.1.1
MatplotLib: 3.1.3
Seaborn: 0.10.0
Scipy: 1.4.1
```

Comment: `Series` is a single column, therefore you can not `merge` it on another column. You can only merge two DataFrames. And yeah, 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'. So instead of providing a Series you must provide a DataFrame as an input and as a `application_data`.

Answer (score 7):

Note that *merge* is a method of *DataFrame*, not *Series*.

So change your code to:

```
application_prev_data = application_data.to_frame().merge(...)
```

(first convert your *Series* to a *DataFrame* (with a single column) and
then *merge*).